# Nonsystem authentication for unprivileged sftpd

Tags: ssh, sftp, pam

I am creating a test system that needs to be able to briefly act as a sftp server on a nonprivalaged port.  The test system runs as a normal user.  So I'm thinking as running sshd with the sftp subsystem configured to use the port and the host key I give it.

However I don't want to be using the system's authentication credentials but my own.  So how do I tell sshd to use something other then systems's passwords?

Alternatively is there a better solution that allows me to fulfil my goals?

Comment: What are your _actual_ goals?

Comment: I want a server that talks the sftp protocol on a port so that when the program I'm testing tries to connect to an sftp server it has an sftp server to connect to.

Comment: I'd consider creating a container; you can then do pretty much whatever you want inside the container.

Comment: A container is a possibility.  Would rather not have to create a container just to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like proftpd will do what I neeed.